# Spatialite queries not loading entirely on canvas

Tags: qgis-3, query, sqlite, sql-view

I connected a SQLite database to my QGIS project. I wrote a query in the DB manager whose result contains 261 elements.

Then, I tried to load the result on the canvas (from the load button at the bottom of the query window) but nothing happened.

So, I created a view (which still contains 261 elements) which appeared in the table list of the database. Then, I added the view to the canvas but only 100 elements are loaded. I don't understand what happened and how to fix this.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You will need to provide more detail, for exemple are you sure that your query produce a valid geometry for your 261 element ?